# delayed run of vba macros in microsoft word

Tags: vba, ms-word, latency

How to intermittently run two macros in a module (two subprocesses) and we have a latency (wait time for example 700 seconds) to request user to change the position of cursor to the desirable location and then second macro will be run based on new position of cursor

Comment: You might want to look into using [Application.OnTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/word.application.ontime). Failing that, you can try the Windows API functions [SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) and [KillTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-killtimer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Main()
    'Here you execute or run the 1st macro
    call Macro1

    'Now we inform the user with a messagebox
    'for the next action they have to take
    'and the time limit within which to complete the action
    'after closing the msgbox
    msgbox "You have 10 seconds after you close this to move your mouse."
    dim WaitUntil
    WaitUntil=Now+timeserial(0,0,10)
    'Wait a certain amount of time
    do while now<=WaitUntil
    doevent
    loop
    
    'Now user must have completed the manual action
    'so we can proceed with the second Macro
    call Macro2
End Sub

Sub Macro1()
    'code
End Sub

Sub Macro2()
    'code
End Sub
```

Comment: While providing a code-only answer may answer the question, it’s recommended to provide an explanation for any additions or edits made. That way, future readers can understand your solution. Please [edit] your answer to add context and/or an explanation to your code.